# How to start a VirtualBox machine via command line (without GUI)?

Tags: virtualbox

I know that this is possible, but I don't know how...

I am just trying to start a VirtualBox VM called `ubuservloc` from the command line, but without success.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Only needed:

```
VBoxManage startvm "VM name" --type headless
```

For example:

```
VBoxManage startvm ubuservloc --type headless
```

Comment: There is also `VBoxHeadless --startvm "VM name"`

Comment: To shut it down use this command: `VBoxManage controlvm "VM name" acpipowerbutton`

Comment: This won't work if the VM is on a saved state with 3D Acceleration on

Comment: Additionally, if your VM uses 3D acceleration, it makes sense to (temporarily) disable it, as it'll prevent the VM from starting in headless mode.

Comment: In case you forgot the names of your VMs, do `VBoxManage list vms`.

Comment: What if I want to specify a file name ?

Comment: @Michael doesn't work. You must register the VM first with VBox.

Comment: For anyone in doubt, `/usr/bin/vboxmanage` is present. I had thought it was just a Windows file.

Answer (score 8):

Try this,

```
virtualbox startvm ubuservloc
```

Comment: works. many thnx.

Answer (score 1):

stop

```
VBoxManage controlvm "vm_name" poweroff
```

start

```
nohup VBoxHeadless -startvm "vm_name" &
```

Answer (score 1):

- To list virtual machines:

  ```
  VBoxManager list vms
  ```
- To Start a virtual machine:

  ```
  VBoxManage startvm YOUR_VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME
  ```
- To stop a virtual machine:

  ```
  VBoxManage controlvm Android poweroff
  ```

Answer (score 0):

- in windows 10

  1. open Oracle VM VirtualBox -> select vm_name right click -> create Shortcut in Desktop
  2. select shortcut -> properties -> shortcut -> target -> copy
  3. open cmd run (change 'VirtualBox.exe' -> 'VBoxHeadless.exe')

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe" --comment "linux_mint" --startvm "14f426cc-845d-46cb-9f6e-4dbb31a3769a"
```