# Shell script to run VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, scripts

I use Virtualbox. Instead of clicking on the button of the name of the virtual machine to run it, I want a shell script that can run a Windows XP virtual machine hosted on Ubuntu machine. Can someone help me please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start a Virtualbox machine via command line (without GUI)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/445284/how-to-start-a-virtualbox-machine-via-command-line-without-gui/449249) or [launch a VM on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/476646/launch-a-vm-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @Tuknutx He asked a shell script, not a command line. He's new.

Comment: @begueradj you are right but this are the right commands in the two links and to use it in a script read this [How do I create a script file for terminal commands?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223691/how-do-i-create-a-script-file-for-terminal-commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> VBox_StopRestoreStart.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 VMNAME_or_UUID"
        exit 1
fi
set -x
VBoxManage controlvm  "$1" poweroff  #enforce turnoff
VBoxManage snapshot   "$1" restorecurrent   #retore state
VBoxManage showvminfo "$1" | grep State   #display state to ensure
VBoxHeadless -s       "$1"  #run in headless mode in background
```

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28611/how-to-automatically-start-and-shut-down-virtualbox-machines)